# Different objects in one when statement (kotlin)

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to render data in an Android app based on the object provided to the Activity. There are 3 types of objects, but two of them have to be treated exactly the same way (the difference doesn't matter in this scenario). Right now, what I do is:

```kotlin
when (someObject) {
    is SourceCash -> {
        transactions = someObject.transactions

        binding.sourceName.text = someObject.name
    }
    is SourceAccount -> {
        transactions = someObject.transactions

        binding.sourceName.text = someObject.name
    }
}
```

This makes me write all the code twice, and also makes it more difficult to fix bugs or make modifications in the future.

The ideal way of handling this would be something like this:

```kotlin
when (someObject) {
    is SourceCash, is SourceAccount -> {
        transactions = someObject.transactions

        binding.sourceName.text = someObject.name
    }
    // And another option here
}
```

That isn't really possible though, since these are different objects and Kotlin is unable to perform a smart cast.

The objects look like this:

```kotlin
data class SourceCash(
    var name: String,
    var country: String,
    var countryCode: String,
    var currency: String,
    var amount: Double,
    var transactions: MutableList<Transaction>
)

data class SourceAccount(
    var name: String,
    var country: String,
    var countryCode: String,
    var currency: String,
    var amount: Double,
    var interest: Double,
    val capitalization: SourceManager.Capitalization,
    var transactions: MutableList<Transaction>
)
```

I tried extending SourceCash in SourceAccount, but that doesn't do the job either.

Is it possible to force kotlin to accept my pinky promise that this property will exist on the given object?

Comment: Create and implement an interface?

Comment: sealed class with default param(s) is another option (abstract class), but I prefer an interface as @Slaw suggested, unless all other types are common.

Comment: I'll look into making it an interface then, thanks

Comment: @Slaw, that should be the answer. I would've upvoted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented an interface as [@Slaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6395627/slaw) suggested and the result is this:

```kotlin
interface Source : Serializable {
    var name: String
    var country: String
    var countryCode: String
    var currency: String
    var amount: Double
    var transactions: MutableList<Transaction>
}
```

And the two objects are:

```kotlin
data class SourceCash(
    override var name: String,
    override var country: String,
    override var countryCode: String,
    override var currency: String,
    override var amount: Double,
    override var transactions: MutableList<Transaction>
) : Source

data class SourceAccount(
    override var name: String,
    override var country: String,
    override var countryCode: String,
    override var currency: String,
    override var amount: Double,
    var interest: Double,
    val capitalization: SourceManager.Capitalization,
    override var transactions: MutableList<Transaction>
) : Source
```

Then in the when statement I do:

```kotlin
when (someObject) {
    is SourceCash, is SourceAccount -> {
        // This cast is safe
        binding.sourceName.text = (someObject as Source).name
        transactions = someObject.transactions
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have three objects to set in the when statement and two are always the same you could do the below. The first item in the when statement would be the 3rd different item you are not including in your code above, then the two you are showing will be caught by the else statement

```
when (someObject) {
    Unknown -> { //where unknown is the 3rd object
        // enter code here
    }
    else -> {
        transactions = someObject.transactions

        binding.sourceName.text = someObject.name
    }
}
```

I have not added any null checks but if someObject could be null you will need to ensure that scenario is managed

Comment: I think this won't work, because the issue is not the when statement itself. These are two different objects and therefore kotlin does not perform a smart cast, so I can't access the object properties. I've implemented a solution with interfaces and I'll post it in a minute

Comment: Apologies. The question stated the problem as having to always write it twice hence my response. It doesn't say you were having problems with casting

Comment: My bad, I might not have been specific enough with my question. I'll specify it in case someone will be looking for an answer to this question in the future